# icingaweb2 Permission denied

Tags: icingaweb2

Please help me to solve this issue with icingaweb

> icinga2: Can't send external Icinga command to the local command file "/var/run/icinga2/cmd/icinga2.cmd": Permission denied.

```
#0 /usr/share/icingaweb2/modules/monitoring/application/forms/Command/Object/ScheduleServiceDowntimeCommandForm.php(191): Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Command\Transport\CommandTransport->send(Object(Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Command\Object\ScheduleHostDowntimeCommand))
#1 /usr/share/icingaweb2/modules/monitoring/application/forms/Command/Object/ScheduleHostDowntimeCommandForm.php(108): Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Forms\Command\Object\ScheduleServiceDowntimeCommandForm->scheduleDowntime(Object(Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Command\Object\ScheduleHostDowntimeCommand), Object(Icinga\Web\Request))
#2 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Web/Form.php(1152): Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Forms\Command\Object\ScheduleHostDowntimeCommandForm->onSuccess()
#3 /usr/share/icingaweb2/modules/monitoring/library/Monitoring/Web/Controller/MonitoredObjectController.php(128): Icinga\Web\Form->handleRequest()
#4 /usr/share/icingaweb2/modules/monitoring/application/controllers/HostController.php(155): Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Web\Controller\MonitoredObjectController->handleCommandForm(Object(Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Forms\Command\Object\ScheduleHostDowntimeCommandForm))
#5 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): Icinga\Module\Monitoring\Controllers\HostController->scheduleDowntimeAction()
#6 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Web/Controller/Dispatcher.php(76): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('scheduleDowntim...')
#7 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Icinga\Web\Controller\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Icinga\Web\Request), Object(Icinga\Web\Response))
#8 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Application/Web.php(384): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(Object(Icinga\Web\Request), Object(Icinga\Web\Response))
#9 /usr/share/php/Icinga/Application/webrouter.php(109): Icinga\Application\Web->dispatch()
#10 /usr/share/icingaweb2/public/index.php(4): require_once('/usr/share/php/...')
#11 {main}
```

Comment: Check with `sudo ls /var/run/icinga2/cmd/icinga2.cmd` if the file exist

Answer (score 3):

In my case (CentOS 7) all I had to do was to ensure the icinga2 feature 'command' was enabled, and restart the service.

```
icinga2 feature enable command
systemctl restart icinga2.service
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is probably correct. You'll need to setup the correct unix permissions for that file. The CentOS7 packages do the right thing there, but for me the problem was related to selinux. Check SELinux denials to see if your commands are being denied:

```
ausearch -m avc --start recent
```

Check the context of the command file:

```
# ls -lZ /var/run/icinga2/cmd/icinga2.cmd
prw-rw----. icinga icingacmd system_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0 /var/run/icinga2/cmd/icinga2.cmd
```

I fixed this by installing the icinga2-selinux package *after* all the other configuration. In particular, you need to (re)install it after enabling the local (named pipe) command transport. After re-installing icinga2-selinux, the correct context should be:

```
# ls -lZ /var/run/icinga2/cmd/icinga2.cmd
prw-rw----. icinga icingacmd system_u:object_r:icinga2_command_t:s0 /var/run/icinga2/cmd/icinga2.cmd
```

Restart icinga2 and Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling selinux will help. 
Temp disable selinux and try again.

```
setenforce 0
```

If it works, try a permanent one.
Edit /etc/selinux/config and make sure

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Comment: Disabling SELinux temporarily for debugging is fine, but there are many better alternatives to permanently disabling an important security feature for the entire system. SELinux can be configured to allow any specific action that you need.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the command feature were enabled. Everything were well installed. I'm using Debian.

I checked when `ls /var/run/icinga -lh` (`lh` options means detailed), and I found that (cleaned output):

```
drwx------ www-data cmd
drwx------ www-data icinga2.pid
```

As the file were ran with root, it didn't have any options on the file. After running `chmod 777 /var/run/icinga2/cmd` or simply change the owner with `chown` command, it will fix it.